# Pearson Correlation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, statistics

As an exercise to help me learn Haskell, I decided to write a small "program" to find the Pearson Correlation Coefficient for 2 lists of numbers.  I'm pretty unhappy with how it turned out, because I feel like the typing is a mess, and it is difficult to read.

I was hoping that someone with experience would help me to improve my code, and tell me how they would have approached the problem.

```
import Data.List



summation :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> a -> (a -> b) -> b
summation i n e = if (i < n)
                  then (e i + summation (i+1) n e)
                  else (e i)

mean :: (Real a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
mean x = (1 / (genericLength x)) *
         (summation 1 (length x) (\i -> realToFrac (x !! (i-1))))

covariance :: (Real a, Fractional b) => [a] -> [a] -> b
covariance x y = (1 / (genericLength x)) *
                 (summation 1 (length x) (\i -> ((realToFrac (x !! (i-1)) - mean x) * (realToFrac (y !! (i-1)) - mean x))))

stddev :: (Real a, Floating b) => [a] -> b
stddev x = ((1 / (genericLength x)) *
             (summation 1 (length x) (\i -> (realToFrac (x !! (i-1)) - mean x) ** 2))) ** (1/2)

pearson :: (Real a, Floating b) => [a] -> [a] -> b
pearson x y = covariance x y / (stddev x * stddev y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Each function on its own

Let us have a look at each of your functions first in solitude. What does `summation` do?

> ```
> summation :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> a -> (a -> b) -> b
> summation i n e = if (i < n)
>                   then (e i + summation (i+1) n e)
>                   else (e i)
> ```

Well, for all numbers from `x` in `i` to `n`, sum the `e x`. We can write this a lot more clear with a list comprehension:

```
summation :: (Enum n, Num a) => n -> n -> a
summation i n e = sum [e x | x <- [i..n]]
```

Note that this only holds if `i` is always lesser than `n` in the inital call.

Next, what does `mean` do?

> ```
> mean :: (Real a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
> mean x = (1 / (genericLength x)) *
>          (summation 1 (length x) (\i -> realToFrac (x !! (i-1))))
> ```

Uh, that looks complicated. First, let us rewrite it as proper fraction:

```
mean x = num / denom 
  where 
    num   = summation 1 (length x) (\i -> realToFrac (x !! (i-1)))
    denom = genericLength x
```

Much easier to read. So, what do you actually do in `num`? You calculate the sum of all numbers in `x`. However, this can be done with `sum` already. We end up with

```
mean :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
mean xs = sum xs / genericLength xs
```

Note that lists are usually named with a suffix `s`. One `x`, multiple `xs`.

We use the same approach on `covariance`. First, we rewrite it in simpler terms:

```
covariance x y = num / denom
  where
    num        = summation 1 (length x) elemwise
    denom      = genericLength x
    elemwise i = (realToFrac (x !! (i-1)) - mean x) * (realToFrac (y !! (i-1)) - mean x))
```

And now we immediately spot an error in `elemwise`. You wrote `y !! (i-1) - mean x`, but you meant `y !! (i - 1) - mean y`.

However, let us have a look at the mathematical definition again:

$$
cov(X,Y) = E\left[(X-E[X])*(Y-E[Y])\right]
$$

Allright. Let's write this exactly down as it stands there:

```
covariance x y = mean productXY
  where
   productXY = pairwiseProduct xSubMean ySubMean
   xSubMean  = subtractMean x
   ySubMean  = subtractMean y
```

This is obviously not ready yet. What are `pairwiseProduct` and `subtractMean`?

```
subtractMean :: Fractional a => [a] -> [a]
subtractMean xs = [x - mx | x <- xs]
  where
    mx = mean xs

pairwiseProduct :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
pairwiseProduct xs ys = zipWith (*) xs ys
```

Now we're done. Note how the `covariance` almost looks like pseudo-code? It's clearly easy to read by a human. That's the **most important** point you should take from this review: make your code easy to read for yourself.

`stddev xs` is just `sqrt (covariance xs xs)`, so you should probably use that:

```
-- sqrt needs Floating
stddev :: Floating a => [a] -> a
stddev xs = sqrt (covariance xs xs)
```

## Everything at once

After we've finished our rewrite, it turns out you don't need `summation` at all. So what do we end up with?

```
mean :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
mean xs = sum xs / genericLength xs

covariance :: Fractional a => [a] -> [a] -> a
covariance xs ys = mean productXY
  where
   productXY = zipWith (*) [x - mx | x <- xs] [y - my | y <- ys]       
   mx        = mean xs
   my        = mean ys

stddev :: Floating a => [a] -> a
stddev xs = sqrt (covariance xs xs)

pearson :: (Floating a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
pearson x y = covariance x y / (stddev x * stddev y)
```

Note that `covariance` got *a lot* easier to read due to bindings.

Please keep in mind that this implementation has some performance related issues. Especially the `mean` implementation [is a poster child for a function that leaks memory](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html), but for small lists you should be fine.

## Working with lists

When you work with lists, avoid element-wise access. It's really slow. Instead, you want to transform the whole map into a single value (a fold, e.g. `length` or `sum`), or into another map (above with list comprehensions, e.g. `[x - mx | x <- xs]`).

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.List

mean :: (Floating a) => [a] -> a
mean x = sum / genericLength x
    where sum = foldl (+) 0 x

covariance :: (Floating a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
covariance x y = (mean xy) - (mean x) * (mean y)
    where xy = zipWith (*) x y

pearson :: (Floating a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
pearson x y = (covariance x y) / (stddev x * stddev y)
    where stddev z = (covariance z z)**0.5
```

#### Learn to use Folds, Maps, Filters and Zips!

They are key concepts of functional programming.

The sum over a list `x` can be written as `foldl (+) 0 x`, a product would be `foldl (*) 1 x`. This is not limited to basic math operations and numbers. You can supply any function on any type of elements.

In a similar manner, `zipWith (*) x y` joins two lists into a list of products.

#### Don't repeat yourself.

Your function `mean`, `covariance` and `stddev` share a lot of code. Never copy-paste code. Create the proper modularisation and reuse it. Here, `covariance` can be reformulated to use only calls to `mean`, and `stddev` is just the self-covariance (and a square root).

Comment: Even better, use the proper functions already defined in the `Prelude`, namely `sum` and `product`. Don't rewrite those yourself. By the way, your (and the OP's) `mean` implementation is the [poster child of a memory leak](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html). And covariance has to traverse each list `x´ and `y` three times: once for `sum`, once for `length` and once for `zipWith`. Writing `covariance` in a memory efficient way isn't as "don't repeat yourself", but your implementation should be fine for small sample sizes.

Comment: Also, `**(0.5)` is called `sqrt`, also in the `Prelude`.

Comment: I like the end result you provide here. What's IMO missing is showing to OP where the problems in the original code are. Your review is "factually correct", but doesn't respect the language competence level of OP. So while the code is good, the review IMO isn't helpful to OP...